# Pyspark reduceByKey is concatenating vs adding

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following spark code creating a key value pair:

```
columnRDD = dataSplit.flatMap(lambda x: enumerate(x)).sortByKey().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Then I have the following which works fine as count of the column elements:

```
countRDD = columnRDD.map(lambda line: (line[0], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2: v1+v2)
```

I have the following code where I want to actually add the numbers together now to create a sum:

```
sumRDD = columnRDD.reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2: v1+v2)
```

and it is producing this result:

```
(1, u'189641895118950189491896018958189561905618948189691896118959189571896818966189671897118972183531811418349183481834718346190531905218305183061831818317183161831518314183131834518322183231832118304182831828218281182791829118311190551905418297182941829218296183031830118302183001829518293183441828018312182991829818310183091830818307182631826918268182671827818277182761827518274182731828818272182601826618265182641824218243182591825818262182891828718261182901825718241182401823918271182861827018285182841822318222182211822018238182561825418255182531823718252182361823518234182501821318214182121893718881189361893518934188801893318947189461894518944181631814218141181991819718177181731819418193181921818518195181841819618174181751817618172181821818318201181811820018098181501813718138182481824618232182451824418219182301823118218182171822918216182151822618209182251822418208182061820318202182281821118210182271835818360183591836118362183361833418337183551835618357190161881318812188111881018792190461904519044188201881818819188141894218943189411894018883189391895518118181191866618665186581867018669186921820719026190281902518743186591869318657186911869018689186881868718668186861869918698186711869718696186951869418991189901898919001190021899918180181781813618148181491813518147181461814518)
```

Which the numbers look like: 18964, 18964

Comment: Is it because the unicode (u'')?

Answer (score 0):

I had to actually convert it to a float to add it together like so:

```
.map(lambda line: (line[0], float(line[1])))
```